# Backbone model undefined, although underscore and backbone loaded

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Trying to create the most basic backbone model, but I'm getting a TypeError.

Underscore is being loaded before backbone. I've grabbed the latest releases.

```
    <script src="src/assets/js-vendor/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/assets/js-vendor/backbone-min.js"></script>

    <script>
    console.log(typeof(_)); // function
    console.log(Backbone.model); // undefined

    var m = Backbone.model.extend({}); // Uncaught TypeError
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run into this issue before. I felt very stupid afterwards.

It's `Backbone.Model.extend()` with a capital M as in `Model`, not `model`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `Backbone.Model`. 'M' need to be capital letter.